# Emacs delete rectangle of more than one page

Tags: emacs

on one page I mark and point my rectangle and use this command ctr+x+r+d to delete the marked rectangle

if the rectangle is spread on 2 pages and more i can't able to mark and point the rectangle
could someone provide how i mark and point rectangle longer than one page (one screen)

Comment: Read http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Understanding-Bug-Reporting.html and then try asking again.

Comment: Please, try to rewrite the question, including more relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the mark with <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>.  Then you can move the point to wherever you want (including several pages down) and delete the rectangle with <kbd>C-x r d</kbd>, the mark does not have to be displayed to work - see http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Setting-Mark.html .

Perhaps you would find it useful to use [M-x transient-mark-mode](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Persistent-Mark.html) - which visually depicts the region by highlighting it.

Comment: C-w is kill-region (cut) by default. For cutting rectangles, use C-x r y.

Comment: lmichelbacher: you mean `C-x r k` to kill a rectangle, and `C-x r y` to yank the killed rectangle. (And `C-x r C-h` to list everything on that prefix, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you select a larger rectangle? Doesn't your emacs auto-scroll when you drag the selection below the lowest line?

Anyway, alternatively you can just type Ctrl-space, move to where you want with the keyboard, and then use Ctrl-x r d.

Answer (score 0):

You should certainly be able to delete a rectangle spanning multiple pages of your buffer, as others have already said. I'm not sure what the issue is there.

I just thought I'd point out a useful alternative, which is provided by `cua-selection-mode`, and which highlights the rectangle you are manipulating. [Trey Jackson made a handy blog about it](http://trey-jackson.blogspot.com/2008/10/emacs-tip-26-cua-mode-specifically.html) which shows all the documentation (or look in the source file, which is cua-base.el).

Place `(cua-selection-mode 1)` into your .emacs and then you can toggle the rectangle editing mode on and off with `C-RET`. When it's on, move point to drag out the rectangle. `DEL` will delete the rectangle, and `C-w` will kill it if you want to be able to yank it back.